# How to change color of Django-tables row?

Tags: django, django-models, html-table, django-tables2

is it possible to change a color of row based on current object's value?

In my case, I have a `table` created from model `Job`. The `Job` has attribute `delivery`. If `job.delivery` is for example 'delivered', I want to change the color of the row to red.

The only thing comes to my mind is to use `JQuery` but I'm not sure if it is not an overkill.

```
class MyOrdersTable(tables.Table):
    edit_entries = tables.TemplateColumn(
            '{% if not record.translator %}<a href="/jobs/update/{{record.id}}">Edit Order</a>{% else %} Can\'t edit order, translator has been assigned. {% endif %}')
    price = tables.Column(default='Not Yet',verbose_name='Price')
    translator = tables.Column(default='Not Yet',verbose_name='Translator')
    progress = tables.TemplateColumn('{{record.delivery.get_status_display}}',verbose_name='Progress')

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 'width': '70%'}
        fields = (
            'translator', 'short_description', 'language_from', 'language_to', 'level', 'created', 'modified', 'price',
            'progress','edit_entries')
        empty_text = """You haven't order a translation yet. Can we help you?"""
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: @Jieter Yes, thank you for your answer, I've forgot to check it solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, as of django-tables2 v1.2.0 you can use [row attributes](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html#row-attributes):

```
class MyOrdersTable(tables.Table):
    # [...]
    class Meta:
        model = Jub
        row_attrs = {
            'data-delivery': lambda record: record.delivery
        }
```

This will render rows like this:

```
<tr [...] data-delivery="delivered"><td>....</tr>
<tr [...] data-delivery="peding"><td>....</tr>
```

You can use the data attribute to target the row with some CSS:

```
tr[data-delivery='deliverd'] {
    background-color: #f2dede;
}
```