# cell color Django-Tables2

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-tables2

**Question: Where do I edit my django code to change the background color of individual cells based on business logic?**

In my views.py I have logic that captures the max value of column 'pts':

```
def show_teams(request):
reg = Teamoffense.objects.filter(~Q(rk='RK'))
pts = Teamoffense.objects.filter(~Q(pts='PTS')).values('pts')
seq = [item['pts'] for item in pts]
maxseq = max(seq)

table = SimpleTable(reg)
table_to_report = RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
if table_to_report:
    return create_report_http_response(table_to_report, request)
return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'table': table,
    'reg': reg,
    'maxseq': maxseq,
})
```

**How can I render any cell with the max value in that column a bgcolor = 'green'?** I currently have a simple table that displays like so:

```
class SimpleTable(TableReport):

class Meta:
    model = Teamoffense
    exclude = ("column1","column2")
    exclude_from_report = ("column1","column2")
    attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

Comment: @Jieter is there a way to do what is accomplished here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513463/how-to-change-color-of-django-tables-row with individual cells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more research looking into the [Django-Tables2 API Docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#table-meta) I found that the [Table.render_foo methods](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html) is what was needed in my case. This changes how the column is rendered. Make sure to set the **column.attrs** and not self.attrs because in my experience this is how I was able to set the individual cell style.

```
#tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import MyTable
from MyApp import views


class SimpleTable(tables.Table):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.maxpts = views.maxpts

    #render_foo example method
    def render_pts(self, value, column):
        if value == self.maxpts:
            column.attrs = {'td': {'bgcolor': 'lightgreen'}}
        else:
            column.attrs = {'td': {}}
        return value


    class Meta:
        model = MyTable
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

Comment: Just to save someone a click....the function name is render_<column name>. So in this example, we are changing the background color for cells in the **pts** column in our table.