# Render cell color for max value in all columns (django)

Tags: django, django-tables2

django-tables2 has a render_foo method that can be defined for each individual column in the table. I wish to avoid a lot of repetitive coding defining a function for each and every column in every table I want to format cells...

Does this package have some way to render_AllColumns? Anything that does this:

```
class simpleTable(tables.Table):
    def render_AllColumns(self, value, column):
        if value == max(column):
            #set column attributes
        else:
            #set other column attributes
        return value
```

I posted about the single column method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757887/cell-color-django-tables2)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no documented/nice way to do this. We have [an issue](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/253) suggesting something you could maybe use, which also points out a workaround.