# Django Tables2 - Format cell based on value from another cell - Blank values causing issues

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using Django Tables2. My goal is to highlight a specific table cell based on the value of another field. I've implemented a solution using [render_foo methods](https://django-tables2-zh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html) (similar to the solution [for this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757887/cell-color-django-tables2)).

I have a Team_Leader Column and I would like it to be highlighted if New_Team_Leader is True (signifying that the Team_Leader has changed). It's working for the most part, except if the Team_Leader is left blank. When the Team_Leader is blank, the cell accepts the formatting from the previous row. Here is my code:

```html
tables.py

import django_tables2 as tables

Class AuditTable(tables.Table):

    
    def render_Team_Leader(self, value, column, record):
        if record.New_Team_Leader == True:
            column.attrs={'td': {'class': 'yellow'}}
        else:
            column.attrs={'td': {}}
        return value
```

This image hopefully demonstrates my problem:

[Highlight rule fails when cell value is None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t23EN.png)

Notice that when the Team_Leader has a value, the highlighting rules work well. When the Team_Leader has not been selected, the cell is highlighted based on the previous record's New_Team_Leader True/False value.

How can I set it up so that the True/False New_Team_Leader formatting rules are applied, even if the Team_Leader is blank?

Comment: Similar to the linked example, does it work to use `column.attrs = {'td': {'bgcolor': 'yellow'}}` instead of a class attribute?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the reply... Tried your idea. Revising the bgcolor attribute had the same "bleeding over" effect for blank values.